# Neo4j - how to improve queries response time?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query returning in 449824 ms. The result set has 44 rows.
This is the query:

`$ match (w:Woka) where (w.woka_title =~ '.Benedictions.') return w.woka_title;`

Here are the relevant indexes:

ON :Woka(author_id)                   ONLINE
ON :Woka(publisher_id)                ONLINE
ON :Woka(language_id)                 ONLINE
ON :Woka(woka_title)                  ONLINE
ON :Woka(woka_id)                     ONLINE

This is the execution plan:

```
Compiler CYPHER 2.2
Planner COST
Projection
  |
  +Filter
    |
    +NodeByLabelScan
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|        Operator | EstimatedRows |     Identifiers |                             Other |
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|      Projection |      14849147 | w, w.woka_title |                      w.woka_title |
|          Filter |      14849147 |               w | w.woka_title ~= /{  AUTOSTRING0}/ |
| NodeByLabelScan |      19798863 |               w |                             :Woka |
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

How I can get faster results?

Comment: Would woka_title become a relationship of any kind? Regular expression matching is a heavy operation. Also, I think regular expressions will avoid indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex matches are not backed by schema indexes. At the moment schema index are solely used for exact matches using `=` and `IN <values>`. Upcoming releases will provide more functionality here.

For now if you want to use regex matches you need to use [manual indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html).